# JavaScript for in - get, combine and process arrays from the main object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an object with the following structure:

```
var PostsData = [
                {
                    postId: 1,
                    postTitle: 'Cuba slam U.S. on human rights',
                    postExcerpt: 'Washington (CNN)U.S. and Cuban officials began a historic round of talks on Wednesday to bridge a 50-year rift in diplomatic relations, but just a day later, the Cuban delegation slammed the United States on its human rights track record.',
                    postTags: ['cuba', 'human rights', 'diplomatics', 'world']
                },
                {
                    postId: 2,
                    postTitle: 'YouTube stars interview Obama',
                    postExcerpt: "In his continuing effort to connect to a younger audience (like the time he went on 'Between Two Ferns'), President Barack Obama sat down with, and took questions, from three YouTube stars: GloZell Green (3 million followers), Bethany Mota (8 million followers) and half of the vlogbrothers (2.4 million followers).",
                    postTags: ['YouTube', 'interview', 'Obama', 'president']
                },
                // etc...
            ];
```

I need to get all values from every "postTags" array from this object (combine all arrays) and after that I need to remove all repeative values from it. As a result I need to extract all tags at once with non repeated values. I am digging in for loops but it's getting very complicated and my knowlage runs out at some point. Can you give me some suggestions about it? Thank you in advance!

(I am using it in Angularjs environment and I was trying nested ng-repeats and I hoped I will come up with something easy but no luck.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery (apply a different syntax as necessary):

```
var containerObject = {},
    finalArray = new Array();
$.each(PostsData, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value.postTags, function(key, value){
        containerObject[value] = true
    });
});
$.each(containerObject, function(key, value) {
    finalArray.push(key)
});
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a magic! Just tested. Thank you very much! Now I need to meditate on it for a while to assimilate what is happening and how the tags are not repeated in the finalArray :)
Can you translate it a bit? :)

Comment: There's really no need to use jQuery for this. Don't add jQuery as a depedency of your app just to do this. Native JavaScript will do just as well (with `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `$.each`).

Comment: Sure. Each tag is mapped as a property of the container object. When you have a repeat value, it simply changes the value of the already existing property, instead of adding a new property. Then we just list the properties of the container object and push them into final array.

Comment: @joews - I used jQuery because it's easy and a dependency of almost every project I have. As I mentioned in the original post, you can apply different syntaxes as necessary. The point was to demonstrate the logic, which this answer does perfectly. Mind removing the down vote?

Comment: It's explicitly not a dependency of most angular.js apps, and the question was not tagged jquery. Including it unnecessarily is not good practice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.protoype.forEach` to build an array of unique tag values:

```
var uniqueTags = PostsData.reduce(function(allTags, post) {  
  post.postTags.forEach(function(tag) { 
    if(allPosts.indexOf(tag) === - 1) {
      allTags.push(tag)
    }
  }); 
  return allTags; 
}, []);
```

Or, if you can use underscore.js or lo-dash:

```
_.chain(PostsData).pluck('postTags').flatten().uniq().value()
```

Comment: Thank you! Written by you doesn't look so complicated as well! :) I didn't know about this reduce method. Thank you very much! It is working and it is exactly what I needed!